# Unable to connect VS Code / Jupiter Notebook to Python-Kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, kernel, junit-jupiter

I recently started to code with Python and therefore wanted to use Jupiter Notebook, but unfortunately, it doesn't connect to the Python-Kernel. I downloaded Python from the official site and from anaconda:

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

I also tried to set the PATH-Variable but that didn't help either:

Used Systems & Versions:

- HP ProBook 450 G6, 64-Bit
- Windows 10 Pro
- VS Code 1.48
- Versions of Python I tried:
  Python 3.8.3 64-Bit (base: conda) - currently installed
  Python 3.7.9 64-Bit
  Python 3.8.5 32-Bit
- current PATH-Variable-Settings:
  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts

Error-Messages:[ErrorMessages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRZrG.png)

Has anyone experienced the same problems?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: used Python-Extension in VS Code: v2020.8.105369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13701

I did the following steps:

- closed vs code entirely
- ran cmd as administrator
- executed following command:
  python -m pip install traitlets==4.3.3 --force-reinstall

Opened VS Code and tried to connect - and it worked.

=)